# How to get count of group by two columns

Tags: scala

The below is myDf

```
fi_Sk   sec_SK      END_DATE
89      42          20160122
89      42          20150330
51      43          20140116
51      43          20130616
82      43          20100608
82      43          20160608
```

The below is my code:

```
val count = myDf.withColumn("END_DATE", unix_timestamp(col("END_DATE"), dateFormat))
                .groupBy(col("sec_SK"),col("fi_Sk"))
                .agg(count("sec_SK").as("Visits"), max("END_DATE").as("Recent_Visit"))
                .withColumn("Recent_Visit", from_unixtime(col("Recent_Visit"), dateFormat))
```

I am getting visits incorrectly,i need to group by(fi_Sk and sec_SK) for counting visits 
the result should be like below :

```
fi_Sk   sec_SK  Visits   END_DATE
89      42        2      20160122
51      43        2      20140116
82      43        2      20160608
```

currently i am getting :

```
fi_Sk   sec_SK  Visits   END_DATE
89      42        2      20160122
51      43        2      20140116
```

Comment: You have the same column names in the groupBy `.groupBy(col("sec_SK"),col("sec_SK"))`

Comment: i changed i am not getting proper visits based on groupby(col("sec_SK"),col("sec_SK"))

Comment: you should be using a window function for that not aggregation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`groupBy` and `aggregation` would aggregate `all the rows in group into one row` but the expected output seems that you want to populate the count for each row in the group. *Window function is the appropriate solution* for you

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
def windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("fi_Sk", "sec_SK")

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.withColumn("Visits", count("fi_Sk").over(windowSpec))
//      .sort("fi_Sk", "END_DATE")
//      .show(false)
//
//    +-----+------+--------+------+
//    |fi_Sk|sec_SK|END_DATE|Visits|
//    +-----+------+--------+------+
//    |51   |42    |20130616|2     |
//    |51   |42    |20140116|2     |
//    |89   |44    |20100608|1     |
//    |89   |42    |20150330|2     |
//    |89   |42    |20160122|2     |
//    +-----+------+--------+------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, apologizes for the changes in the question, i have modified little in my expected output. i need to group by(fi_Sk and sec_SK and max of END_DATE) and i need to show the visits count.

Comment: doesn't your code give you the correct result @Mahi. whats wrong with your code and whats the unexpected output?

Comment: i am not getting the expected result, i have added current output in the question please find.

Comment: looking your code you should be getting as you expected. So you must be doing one more groupBy with only `fi_Sk`. debug your code by printing after each transformation and you will see where you made the mistake